# How to test asynchronous function with no return with Jasmine

Tags: angular, asynchronous, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test this function with Jasmine. This function is **not** in the service file but another component

```
    getPolicyUrl() {
    this.insuranceService.getData(this.endpointURL).subscribe((response) => {
      this.insuranceTermsUrl = response.PolicyUrl;
    });
  }
```

So far what I've done is:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TermsDetailsComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});



it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });



 it('should change the value of terms url variable', () => {
    component.insuranceTermsUrl = '';

    component.getPolicyUrl();

    expect(component.insuranceTermsUrl).toEqual(
      'https://google.com'
    );
  });
```

In providers I have also included my InsuranceService.

Unfortunately I get an error :

*Error: Expected '' to equal 'https://google.com'.*

I guess expect is called before the url gets overwritten in the component. I tried using spyOn, async await, done() but nothing helped. I dont want to change original function to-be-tested not adding return to it. Appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

You need to spy on the `getData` on the insuranceService and provide a mock response.

Try something like this:

```
let insuranceService: InsuranceService;
beforeEach(() => {
  // !! get a handle on insurance service
  insuranceService = TestBed.inject(InsuranceService);
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TermsDetailsComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});



it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


 // !! wrap test in fakeAsync so we have better control of the subscribe
 it('should change the value of terms url variable', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(insuranceService, 'getPolicyUrl').and.returnValue(of({ PolicyUrl: 'https://google.com' }));
    component.insuranceTermsUrl = '';

    component.getPolicyUrl();
    
    // !! call tick to make the subscribe happen before the assertion
    tick();
    expect(component.insuranceTermsUrl).toEqual(
      'https://google.com'
    );
  });
```

This is a great resource in learning how to test components depending on services: https://testing-angular.com/testing-components-depending-on-services/#testing-components-depending-on-services.